# Pine script - Close price, deeper well

Tags: pine-script

How can plotshape the deeper well like below?

[image]

When the current close is smaller than the last close (close[1]).

```
// © BrunofAlmeida25

//@version=4
study(title="New lesson", overlay=true)

//calcular fechamento 
fecha=iff(close < close[1] and close[1] > close[2] and close[2] > close[3] and close[3] > close[4], close, na)

//plot da condição
plotchar(fecha, char="★", location=location.belowbar, color=timeframe.isdaily ? color.yellow : na)
```

I already have that but isn´t correct because I have things like below.

[image]

How can you see the current close is bigger than the last close but have a shape...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be looking for something like this:

```
//@version=4
study("", "", true)
cond = close < min(open[1], close[1])
plotchar(cond, "cond", "•", location.belowbar)
```

[image]

Comment: when price have a break

Comment: Don't understand.

Comment: i want plot only when have a trend break but i dont know how

Comment: To branch out to another question, you should create a new one, as this question was answered and accepted.